# RequestMapping with POST in Spring not working?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Hi I have the following ajax call in my client side.

```
 var arr = JSON.stringify(JSON_Array);
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: arr,
            dataType: 'text',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function () {
                console.log("Success!");
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("error");
            },
            
        });
```

Server side:

```
@Controller
public class Controller{
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String start() {
        System.out.println("works"); //prints
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "text/plain")
    public void process(@RequestBody String payload) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("payload "  + payload); //does not print
    }
}
```

The ajax call is successfully sent off, however nothing is received in the server side. The process method is not being used. I am not too sure why. Help would be appreciated.

edit:
Changes made following @Toofy's comment

In Ajax call:

```
dataType: 'text',
contentType: "text/plain;",
```

process method kept the same.

I also tried changing the Ajax call to the following

```
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json;",
```

and the server side changes:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public void process(@RequestBody String payload) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("payload "  + payload);
    }
```

in both these cases the ajax calls stop working

Comment: I presume it's because you're sending it off as json and your process method is explicitly asking for text/plain ?

Comment: @Toofy I have made an edit to account for your comment

Comment: is start() supposed to be a GET method?

Comment: it's a method to load the index.html page which is in the templates folder. It's running with thymleaf

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by doing the following:

In Ajax call I got rid of dataType

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/',
      type: 'POST',
      data: arr,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",          
});
```

In the server side I changed the process method to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void process(@RequestBody String payload) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(payload);
}
```